# Is it possible for matplotlib's alpha transparency values to "sum" to 1?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, alpha

I am using matplotlib to plot a series of horizontal lines that overlap.  I would like to indicate (in a very rough way) how much overlap there is via transparency.  For example if I have ten lines and 5 of them overlap over a certain interval, I would like that interval to have an alpha value of 0.5.  If all of them overlap over a certain interval then the interval should have an alpha value of 1.0. The following code should illustrate what I want:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]
x_start = [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
x_end = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

plt.hlines(y, x_start, x_end, linewidth=7, colors='red', alpha=0.1)
plt.hlines(1.2, 0, 10, linewidth=7, colors='red', alpha=1)
plt.ylim(0.8, 1.4)
plt.show()
```

[image: Image of two lines with different transparencies]

I would like the transparency of the red from x=0 to x=1 for the line at y=1 to be the same as that of the horizontal line at y=1.2 (not transparent at all).  However this is not the case.

Is there a way to achieve what I want with matplotlib and the alpha values?  I will know the total number of lines that can possibly overlap (i.e., how many lines overlapping should correspond to 0 transparency).

Comment: Layers with transparency `s` and `d` add together to have transparency `s+d(1-s)` (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_compositing).  With two layers of alpha 0.5 it's easy to see that the sum isn't quite opaque; the alpha will be over `1/n` for all `n`. ( The polynomial expansion seems a little familiar, maybe there's a trick for the root.)

Comment: ha, check this out: http://twvideo01.ubm-us.net/o1/vault/gdc07/slides/S3721i1.pdf; approximates the general problem.

Comment: @cphlewis Thanks, I used your transparency equation and the link to come up with an approximation that works for me (see below).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @cphlewis who got me pointed in the right direction I now have an approximation that works well enough for my needs.

My problem is much easier than the general problem since I want to assign each line (layer) the exact same transparency level `s`.  If there are `n=2` lines I want the transparency when both lines overlap to be close to 0, e.g. `alpha=0.97`.

If `n=2` and `alpha=0.97`, solving

```
0.97 = s + s(1-s)
```

for `s` yields `s=0.827`.

Generalizing this for any `n` leads to solving a polynomial where the coefficients are given by the n'th row of [Pascal's triangle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle) and where the sign of each coefficient is equal to

```
(-1)^(n + pos)
```

where `pos` is the position of the coefficient in Pascal's triangle from left to right and where `pos` starts at 1.  Also, the last coefficient in Pascal's triangle is replaced with the desired `alpha` value.

So for `n=5` the polynomial to be solved is

```
s^5 - 5s^4 + 10s^3 - 10s^2 + 5s - 0.97 = 0
```

The following Python code solves for the smallest real root (which is the `alpha` value that I want) given `n` and `alpha` (note that `alpha < 1`).

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg

num_lines = 5
end_alpha_value = 0.97  ## end_alpha_value must be in the interval (0, 1)

pascal_triangle = scipy.linalg.pascal(num_lines + 1, kind='lower')

print 'num_reps: 1, minimum real root: %.3f' % end_alpha_value
for i in range(2, num_lines + 1):
    coeff_list = []
    for j, coeff in enumerate(pascal_triangle[i][:i]):
        coeff_list.append(coeff * ((-1)**(i+j+1)))
    coeff_list.append(-end_alpha_value)

    all_roots = np.roots(coeff_list)
    real_roots = all_roots[np.isreal(all_roots)]
    min_real_root = min(real_roots)
    real_valued = min_real_root.real[abs(min_real_root.imag) < 1e-5]

    print 'num_reps: %i, minimum real root: %.3f' % (i, real_valued[0])
```

For the case `n=10` if the desired transparency is `alpha=0.97` then `s=0.296` resulting in the following output:
[image: Imgur]

I believe what is going on shows up better using black as the color:
[image: Imgur]

Comment: realized overnight that no overlay of translucent layers will be completely opaque -- letting y% of x% of the light through is still letting a little light through. So smallest real root, as you say. That's a nice case of physical intuition and real vs complex roots of a relatively simple equation, I bet I'll use it pedagogically.

Comment: Post the updated graphic as an example? I'd also like to see it as a data-visualization tactic.